# Clustered standard errors with imputed and weighted data in R

Tags: r, imputation, r-mice, weightit

I am attempting to get clustered SEs (at the school level in my data) with data that is both imputed (MICE) and weighted (CBPS). I have tried a couple different approaches that have thrown different errors.

This is what I have to start, which works fine:

```
library(tidyverse)
library(mice)
library(MatchThem)
library(CBPS)

tempdata <- mice(d, m = 10, maxit = 50, meth = "pmm", seed = 99)

weighted_data <- weightthem(trtmnt ~ x1 + x2 + x3,
                            data = tempdata,
                            method = "cbps",
                            estimand = "ATT")
```

Using this (https://www.r-bloggers.com/2021/05/clustered-standard-errors-with-r/) as a guide, I attempted all 3, which all resulted in various types of error messages.

My data is in a restricted server so unfortunately I can't bring it into here to reproduce things exactly, although if it's useful I could attempt to recreate some sample data.

So attempting with `estimatr` first, I get this error:

```
m1 <- estimatr::lm_robust(outcome ~ trtmnt + x1 + x2 + x3,
                          clusters = schoolID,
                          data = weighted_data)

Error in eval_tidy(mfargs[[da]], data = data) :
  object 'schoolID' not found
```

I have no clue where the schoolID variable would have dropped out/not be recognized. It isn't part of the weighting procedure but it should still be in the data frame...if I use it as a covariate in a standard model without clustering, it's there.

I also attempted with `miceadds` and got this error:

```
m2 <- miceadds::lm.cluster(outcome ~ trtmnt + x1 + x2 + x3,
                           cluster = "schoolID",
                           data = weighted_data)

Error in as.data.frame.default(data) : 
  cannot coerce class `"wimids"` to a data.frame
```

And finally, with `sandwich` and `lmtest`:

```
library(sandwich)
library(lmtest)

m3 <- weighted_models <- with(weighted_data,
                              exp=lm(outcome ~ trtmnt + x1 + x2 + x3))

msandwich <- coeftest(m3, vcov = vcovCL, cluster = ~schoolID)

Error in UseMethod("estfun") :
   no applicable method for `estfun` applied to an object of class "c(`mimira`, `mira`)"
```

Any ideas on any of the above methods, or where to go next?

Answer (score 1):

You were really close. You need to use `with(weighted_data, .)` to fit a model in your weighted datasets, and you need to use `estimatr::lm_robust()` to get the clustered standard errors. So try the following:

```r
weighted_models <- with(weighted_data,
                        estimatr::lm_robust(outcome ~ trtmnt + x1 + x2 + x3,
                                            cluster = schoolID))
```

Your first and second approaches were incorrect because you supplied `weighted_data` to a single model as if it were a data frame, but it's not; it's a complicated `wimids` object. You need to use the `with()` infrastructure to fit a model to the imputed weighted data.

Your third approach was close, but `coeftest()` needs to be used on a single model, not a `mimira` object, which contains all the models fit the imputed datasets. Although you can use `coeftest()` inside `with()` with `mira` objects, you cannot do so with `mimira` objects from `MatchThem`. This is where `estimatr::lm_robust()` comes in since it is able to apply the clustering within each imputed dataset.

I also recommend you take a look at this [blog post](https://ngreifer.github.io/blog/treatment-effects-mi/) on estimating treatment effects after weighting with multiply imputed data. The only difference in your case to the code presented in the post is that you would change `vcov = "HC3"` to `vcov = ~schoolID` in whichever function you use.